# XSLT - Change the order of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml linke this,

```
<person-group>
    <name>
        <surname>Agate</surname>
        <given-names>R. J.</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Choe</surname>
        <given-names>M.</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Arnold</surname>
        <given-names>A. P.</given-names>
    </name>
</person-group>
```

in the output xml, I have to change the order of `<surname>` and `<given-names>` as `<given-names>` and `<surname>` expect first node . so the output xml should look like,

```
<person-group>
    <name>
        <surname>Agate</surname>
        <given-names>R. J.</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <given-names>M.</given-names>
        <surname>Choe</surname>   
    </name>
    <name>    
        <given-names>A. P.</given-names>
        <surname>Arnold</surname>
    </name>
</person-group>
```

I wrote following xsl to do this task,

```
<xsl:template match="person-group">
        <person-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </person-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[position()=1]">
        <name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::surname" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::given-names" />
        </name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[position()>1]">
        <name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::given-names"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::surname"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="surname" >
        <surname>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </surname>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="given-names" >
        <given-names>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </given-names>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this, doubled the content of `<name>` nodes and gave me a output like this,

```
<person-group>
    <name>
        <surname>Agate</surname>
        <given-names>R. J.</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <given-names>M.</given-names>
        <surname>Choe</surname>
        <given-names>M.</given-names>
        <surname>Choe</surname>
    </name>
    <name>
        <given-names>A. P.</given-names>
        <surname>Arnold</surname>
        <given-names>A. P.</given-names>
        <surname>Arnold</surname>
    </name>
</person-group>
```

How can I modify my code to get the expected result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need an identity template and the template override for `name` nodes whose position is greater than 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[position() &gt; 1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="given-names,surname"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And as it is XSLT 2.0 the two `<xsl:apply-templates select="given-names"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="surname"/>` can be shortend to `<xsl:apply-templates select="given-names, surname"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited my answer. Thanks Martin!